# Django CountryField COUNTRIES_OVERRIDE & COUNTRIES_FIRST -- NOT WORKING

Tags: django, django-models

CountryField is working, but "United States of America" is too long, I prefer just "United States" or even "USA".

Also, I want USA & GB at the top of the list when you pull down the pull down.

When I first implemented COUNTRIES_OVERRIDE & COUNTRIES_FIRST, they were working.  Then suddenly they stopped working, and have not worked since.

I have been pulling my hair out!  (Not literally.)

In the models.py file where I import CountryField, I also import settings from django_countries.conf.  Below the import lines, and above the model defintion that uses CountryField, I have these lines:

```
settings.COUNTRIES_FIRST = [ 'US', 'GB' ]
settings.COUNTRIES_OVERRIDE = { 'US': 'USA' }
```

Troubleshooting tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Any error you are getting ? Please post what are you getting as output with traceback.

Comment: Not getting any error.  Moving the settings code to my settings file solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t reliably alter settings from other modules. Remove those lines from your `models.py`, and set the values in your `settings.py`:

```
COUNTRIES_FIRST = [ 'US', 'GB' ]
COUNTRIES_OVERRIDE = { 'US': 'USA' }
```

Comment: Ah!  Moving the code to my settings file solved the problem. Thanks,

Comment: to set an initial default value along with a default country flag check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563354/django-countries-dropdown-default